# Ebene vs. Niveau vs. Aus­maß

Tags: word-usage, difference, word-choice

**Ebene**, **Niveau**, and **Aus­maß** — all these three words could be translated to English as a **Level**.

When and which word should I choose when I have to use the word **Level** in German?

English examples:

- There is an agreement at the international level.
- According to your level of competence...
- The integration level between the EU members...

Could someone explain the application practice.

Comment: Have you tried to look them up in the opposite direction (German → English)? There you would find additional meanings.

Comment: @amadeusamadeus, yeap, I've checked at Pons, there one can see dozens of examples, I would like to see more common samples from a real-life.

Comment: @MikeB. And I would like to see your examples where you could use level in English, and maybe another term in English that would fit in that specific example much more "natural". So it would become possible to show the distinction between one and the other level.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm, done, the question has been updated.

Comment: And what nobody has mentioned so far: you can just use _Level_ in many cases. It's a common enough loanword with quite the same connotations as the Enlish usages for "extent", "degree", or sometimes "elevation".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Niveau** can mean *level (of knowledge, difficulty, wages)*, but also *elevation*, hence probably being the accurate translation in most cases
- **Ebene** means mostly *layer* or *(the) plains*, rarely also *floor* in bigger buildings. However, *level* meaning *floor* should be rather translated *Stock(werk)*
- **Ausmaß** usually means *extent*

Comment: Thanks and what about _«There is an agreement at the international level»_?

Comment: @MikeB. in German there's a *layer* metaphor for such hierarchical levels, hence *auf internationaler Ebene*

Comment: "at international level" is "auf internationaler Ebene", Niveau or Ausmaß don't fit. IMHO *Ebene* means *Level* in most cases, whereas *Layer* usually means *Schicht*.